# Car jerking at certain engine RPM

Tags: volvo, motors, oil-filter

I drive a 1996 model Volvo 440 GL(manual gear box). When the engine RPM reaches around 2000 - 3000 range, car starts jerking. It feels like the car needs to go faster but something is not allowing.

- full coverage preparation 2 months ago
- strap change 10k km ago
- fluid levels seems okay
- motor filter has not been changed for 50k km and not for at least 1.5 years

The car has remained unused for a month, few times

**What can be the most likely cause of such a behaviour?**

Comment: Before people down vote questions like this, you *really* need to take into consideration that English may not be their first language. Don't be mean because of this. If you don't understand something, please ask questions to clarify.

Comment: I take it your comment is prophylactic? Nobody appears to have downvoted anything...

Comment: There was one downvote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If when you shift gear and release the clutch you feel the engine reving up without the car actually accelerating, probably the clutch is worn or very old/used. (this goes for manual gearbox)

Answer (score 2):

If I am understanding what you are trying to say, it sounds like the transmission is slipping and allowing the engine to rev higher than what you'd expect for the speed you are going. Not knowing if it is an automatic or standard gearbox, I'm going to assume it is auto, because I don't think Volvo made too many standard shift 4-doors.

Something you need to check is the transmission fluid. First, while everything is warm, check the level of the fluid in the transmission. While you are doing this, check the color and smell. You want an oil smell with clear red fluid. If you smell a burnt smell and the fluid looks brown. You can try to change the fluid to see if it helps, but this is usually just a temporary fix. Once the fluid is burnt, it usually only a matter of time before the transmission is done.

If the fluid seems good, it doesn't mean there isn't a problem with the tranny. You may want to run it by a transmission shop and see what they think. Don't forget to get a second opinion with a mechanic you trust.

If you check the tranny and it seems okay, you'll have to post up more information about what is going on so we can give you better advice.

**EDIT:** With the new knowledge of a standard transmission, I would suggest the clutch is slipping as suggested.

Comment: Manual gear box but probably not so much difference.